# Mean value theorem for Improper Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,\infty)$ and $\phi(x)\geq0$ and be integrable in $[a,\infty) $ then there exists some 
>   $c\in(a,\infty)$ such that
>
> $$\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)\phi(x) dx = f(c)\int_{a}^{\infty}\phi(x) dx$$

I tried $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)\phi(x) dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}   \int_{a}^{n} f(x)\phi(x)dx$. Can we apply mean value theorem for proper integrals to the latter integral and then take limit?

Comment: But what if the integral is divergent?

Comment: @Dhanvi Sreenivasan We are assuming that the integral is convergent

Comment: If the integral is convergent, that poses some additional conditions on $f$ and $\phi$.. this seems arbitrary

Comment: @user251257 can you please provide a short proof for your statement

Comment: If you are assuming the integral on the left is convergent, then you should say so. Right now it appears only the integral on the right is assumed to be convergent.

Answer (score 6):

**Caution: The statement is wrong, even not well-defined, if the integrals are allowed to be non-finite!** However, if the integrals are finite, the statement is true.

**Following assumptions are crucial:**

Assume $\int_I \phi$ and $\int_I f\phi$ to be finite where $I = [a, \infty)$ (as stated in the comment).
For convenience, assume $\int_I \phi = 1$ without loss of generality, as for $\int_I \phi = 0$ we have $\phi = 0$ almost everywhere and the statement is trivially true.

**Proof:**

Let $m = \inf_I f$ and $M = \sup_I f$, which may be non-finite.
As $m \le f \le M$ and the integral is monotone, we have
$$ m \le \int_I f \phi \le M. $$
(That is obviously still valid if $m = -\infty$ or $M = \infty$.)

1. Case $M = \int_I f\phi$. As we assume $\int_I f\phi$ to be finite, we have $M < \infty$.
   Assume the contrary that $f(x) < M$ for every $x\in I$. Then, for every non-empty compact subset $K\subseteq I$ we have $\min_{K} (M - f) > 0$ by continuity of $f$. Now, as
   $$ 1 = \int_I \phi = \lim_{b\to \infty} \int_a^{b} \phi,$$
   there exists some $b_0$ with $\int_{a}^{b_0} \phi > 0$.
   In particular, we have
   $$ \int_I \underbrace{(M-f)\phi}_{\ge 0} \ge \int_a^{b_0} (M-f)\phi \ge \min_{x\in [a, b_0]}(M-f(x)) \int_a^{b_0}\phi > 0, $$
   a contradiction. Thus, $f < M$ is false, and there exists some $c_M\in I$ with $f(c_M) = M$.
2. Case $m = \int_I f\phi$: Likewise, we have $m > -\infty$ and there exists some $c_m\in I$ with $f(c_m) = m$.
3. Case $m < \int_I f\phi < M$: We have $\int_I f\phi \in f(I)$, as $f$ is continuous and, thus $f(I)$ is an interval. In particular, there exists $c\in I$ with
   $$ \int_I f \phi = f(c). $$

The proof (with minor modification) also applies to $f$ restricted on $(a,\infty)$. As the integral remains the same, thus there is also a $c\in (a, \infty)$ with $\int_I f\phi = f(c)$.

Alternatively, if $\int_I f\phi = f(a)$ then there exists some $c\in (a,\infty)$ with $f(a) = f(c)$. To prove this, assume the contrary: For every $x\in(a,\infty)$ we have $f(x) \ne f(a)$. Then, as consequence of the intermediate value theorem, we have either $f(x) > f(a)$ for all $x\in(a,\infty)$ or $f(x) < f(a)$ for all $x\in(a,\infty)$. Thus we obtain $\int_I f\phi > f(a)$ or $\int_I f\phi < f(a)$ respectively, which is a contradiction to $\int_I f\phi = f(a)$.

Comment: I want c in (a,$\infty$). Open interval

Comment: Why do you think $f$ is bounded?

Comment: @zhw. I do not need that $f$ is bounded, if $\int_I f\phi$ is finite.

Comment: @user251257 How do i get c $\in$ (a,$\infty$) . Please give some hint.

Comment: @user251257 what do mean by "fixed the answer"?

Comment: @usee251257 Thank you so much. Really thank you so much

Comment: @user251257 you are amazing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109110/discussion-between-user775902-and-user251257).

Comment: @user251257 what if m=-$\infty$ or M= $\infty$?

Comment: @user251257 Sorry. I can't understand. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @user251257 please explain.

Comment: @user251257 Please answer. This question is very important for me.

Comment: @user775902 Assume $m=-\infty$. Then item 1 or 3 apply. In both cases, the conclusion is valid (as I proved it). Likewise, for $M=\infty$, item 2 or 3 apply.

Comment: @usee251257 Can you please provide a reference for m=-$\infty$ and M=$\infty$

Comment: @user251257 if m=-$\infty$ or M=$\infty$ then can we write m$\leq$f$\leq$M

Comment: @user251257 please answer sir.

Comment: @user775902 please read my answer(s). Your question is already answered.

Comment: @user251257 if m=-$\infty$ or M=$\infty$ then is your inequality that m $\leq$ f $\leq$ M true???

Comment: @user775902: what do you think and why?

Comment: @user251257 at the points $\infty$ and -$\infty$ is f bounded???

Comment: @user775902: No. $m \le f \le M$ means that $f$ takes values between $m$ and $M$ (may including $m$ and $M$). So, if $m=-\infty$ or $M=\infty$, is that inequality true?

Comment: @user251257 i don't think that the inequality is true. Can you please provide a reference supporting you answer. Please sir

Comment: @user775902: $f$ takes values in the reals. By definition of $\infty$, any real number is less than $\infty$ and any real number is greater than $-\infty$. So the inequality is true.

Comment: @user251257 but we have a less than equal to inequality.

Comment: @user775902: "less than" implies "less than or equal"

Comment: @user251257 Closure of J = [m,M]. What if m=-$\infty$ or M= $\infty$. Mean value theorem in all books is given for definite integral. Is it also true for improper integral??

Comment: @user775902: So? What is your question?

Comment: @user251257 In definite integrals f is continuous on [a,b] implies f is bounded and hence we get a mean value theorem. In improper integrals f may be unbounded

Comment: @user251257 please reply sir.

Comment: @user251257 my question is in [a,$\infty$) is mean value theorem applicable?.

Comment: @user775902: I proved it in my answer. That was the point of your post.

Comment: @user251257 In any book i can't find mean value theorem for improper integrals. Can you give me a reference of your proof?

Comment: @user251257 closure of J= [m,M] what if m=-$\infty$ or M= $\infty$????

Comment: @user251257 Your answer is'nt correct for infinity and - infinity case. Can you please deal these cases seperately.

Comment: @user251257 i am sorry. Please don't stop answering. This question is very important for my PhD

Comment: @user251257 so your proof requires extended real numbers?

Comment: @user775902: I have extensively reviewed the proof. I hope it is easier to understand now.

Comment: @user251257 f may be unbounded then we cannot talk about its sup or inf. How does your argument holds ???

Comment: @user775902 it is just $-\infty$ or $\infty$. I have never said that they are finite

Comment: @user251257 So what happens if sup =$+ \infty$???

Comment: @user775902 we have that discussion already. If $\sup = \infty$ case 2 and case 3 apply.

Comment: @user251257 If sup =$\infty$ then how $\int$ $f\phi$ < M???

Comment: @user775902: $M=\infty$ and $\int f\phi$ by assumption finite. any finite value is less than $\infty$ by definition.

Comment: @user775902 could it be that you think that an unbounded function always has non-finite integral?

Comment: @user251257 how can we write m$\leq$ f$\leq$M If M is $\infty$ or m is -$\infty$ then??

Comment: @user251257 i am asking about f?? How is f $\in$ [m,M]

Comment: @user775902 I have answered that before. Each image under $f$ is a real number by definition of $f$. Each real number is less than $\infty$ and greater than $-\infty$ by definition. "Less than" implies "less than or equal". The same for "greater than".

Comment: @user251257 Everyone is objecting in f $\in $[m,M] . f is continuous in [a,b] then f is bounded but here the interval is not closed.

Comment: @user775902 I can't help if "everyone" thinks that $[-\infty, \infty]$ is bounded, or that $f\in [-\infty, \infty]$ is wrong for a real-valued function, or that they can't read that I never claimed that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @user251257 How can we talk about sup or inf if the function is not bounded.?

Comment: @user775902 again, if you have doubts about my proof, just open a question and if that proof is valid.

Comment: @user775902 why not? I have never claimed that the supremum is taken in the real numbers. It is rather common to take the supremum in $[-\infty, \infty]$ if one does not know that the values are bounded.

Comment: @user251257 So you are saying that supremum may be $\infty$ and infimum may be -$\infty$

Comment: @user775902: Yes. since day one. In fact I have explicitly stated it twice in the answer.

Comment: @user251257 I am sorry but my professors cannot understand your proof.

Comment: @user775902: It might tell more about your professors than about my proof.

Comment: @user251257 my professor said if -$\infty $ $\leq$f $\leq $ $\infty$ then every function is bounded??

Comment: @user775902: Is that a question? Does your professor think that $-\infty \le f \le \infty$ implies that $f$ is bounded with respect to the usual ordering on $\mathbb R$? I will stop answering. If you like, post that as question.

Comment: @user251257 Please don't stop answering. Please just revise your answer and make it simpler.

Comment: @user775902: I know no proof that is simpler. As I am happy with the proof. I see no reason to revisited it. If you think going through the cases $f$ is bounded, $f$ is unbounded from blow, and $f$ is bound from above makes the proof more clear to you so be it. But you will see that you are doing the same  steps in each cases.

Comment: @user251257 Ok sir. As you wish.

Comment: @user251257 I have found a counterexample to this. Take f(x)=sin x and $\phi$(x)=e$^{-x} $ and a=1 then you cannot find a c$\in$(1,$\infty$). Integral is calculated as https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%ABe%5E%28-x%29+sin+x+dx+x%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: @user775902: for your example $\int_1^\infty f\phi / \int_1^\infty \phi = \frac12(\sin(1) + \cos(1)) \approx 0.69$. Do you really think, that 0.69 is not in $[-1, 1] = \sin([1,\infty))$?

Comment: @user251257 we want a c$\in$ (1,$\infty$)? What is our c in this case?

Comment: @user251257 sin$ ^{-1}$(0.69)$\notin$ (1,$\infty$)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin+inverse+0.69

Comment: @user775902 you do know that sine is $2\pi$ periodic, right?

Comment: @user251257 yes i know that

Comment: @user775902 so is there a $c>1$ with $\sin(c) = \frac12 (\sin(1) + \cos(1))$?

Comment: @user775902 Can you please explicitely state c $>1$..

Comment: @user775902 that is what you, don't you?

Comment: @user251257 what is the value of c. Please tell me

Comment: @user251257 so our c=2$\pi$+0.761489 radians?

Comment: @user775902 for example

Comment: @user251257 what???

Comment: @user251257 i could not get you.

Comment: @user775902 there many $c$ with that property, as you can always add $2\pi$ to it.

Comment: @user251257 Thank you so much