# For some $c\in(1,\infty)$, $\frac{\int_{(1,\infty)-C}g(x)\phi(x) dx}{\int_{(1,\infty)-C} \phi(x)dx }=g(c)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

C is a Countable set. $g$ is continuous  in $ [1,\infty)$ and $\phi(x)>0, \forall x\in[1,\infty)-C$.    $\phi(x)$ and $g(x)\phi(x)$ are integrable in $[1,\infty)-C$.

Prove that there exists a $c\in(1,\infty)-C$ such that:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\int_{(1,\infty)-C} g(x)\phi(x) dx}{\displaystyle  
 \int_{(1,\infty)-C}    \phi(x)dx
  }=g(c)$$
g(x)= $(x^{1-\sigma}-x^\sigma)cos (t lnx), 0<\sigma<1$
$\phi(x)=1-x+[x]/x^2$ where [.] denotes the greatest integer function.
$C= \{x \mid cos (tlnx)=0\}$

Comment: Looks like an adaptation of [Mean-Value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals)?

Comment: @gt6989b Yes it can be mean value theorem for improper integrals.

Comment: @gt6989b The very good user have you given a link to have an answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano That link is for definite integrals. But here the integral is improper

Comment: are we allowed to manipulate $\phi(x)$? as in give it some new definition?

Comment: $min g(x) \leq g(x) \leq max g(x) $

Comment: @C Squared yes we can manipulate it.

Comment: @kingW3 but g may not be bounded. How will max and min exist?? g is defined on [1,\infty)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712287/mean-value-theorem-for-improper-integrals I think you can find an answer here

Comment: @anadita I'm pretty sure that $g$ has to be bounded for the integral to exist since $g$ is continuous but I'm not sure how to prove it atm.

Comment: @kingW3 g may be unbounded.

Comment: @PAM1499 I  am not satisfied by the answer

Comment: @C Squared please reply about the answer after manipulating $\phi(x)$ and giving it a new definition

Comment: Yet another solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3758530/a-question-about-mean-value-theorem-for-integrals/3759723#3759723

Comment: @Oliver Diaz What if we substract a Countable set from the domain. Will the result hold then?

Comment: @ananditakumari: did you just edited the original problem? That is now completely different problem. In the future, create a entirely new problem when the edits are such that they change the nature of problem.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz It is slightly different. A countable set has measure 0 so we can substract a countable set from the domain

Comment: Don't use `\displaystyle` in the title; and avoid all $\rm\LaTeX$ titles.

Comment: @ananditakumari: it is completely different since that allows for bad singularities on the points of discontinuity.

Comment: And stop harassing users in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz Why will we have discontinuities?

Answer (score 3):

You can't prove it, because it is not true.

Consider $\phi(x)=g(x)=e^{-x}$ and $C=\{1+\log 2\}$. Then the left-hand-side is $1/2e$, but $g(x)=1/2e$ if and only if $x=1+\log 2$.

(Note that if you drop the condition $c\notin C$ and just require that $c\in(1,\infty)$, then the usual proof of the mean value theorem for integral works.)

Comment: so you found a c>1. Then why is it not true??

Comment: @ananditakumari $c$ is a member of $C$, so it does not satisfy $c\in (1,\infty)\setminus C$.

Comment: how do you calculate the integral for the restricted domain$ [1],\infty)-C$?

Comment: @ananditakumari Just ignore that point, as it is Lebesgue measure 0.

Comment: so the statement is not true?