# Prove that $\Re(\rho)=1/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Given $$\frac{\mid \int_{x=1}^\infty(\frac{1-x+[x]}{x^2})x^{1-\bar{\rho}} dx\mid}{  \mid \int_{x=1}^\infty(\frac{1-x+[x]}{x^2})x^\rho dx\mid  }=1$$ where [x] denotes the greatest integer function and $\rho$ and $\bar{\rho}$ are complex constants such that $0<\Re(\rho)<1$. Prove that $\Re(\rho)=1/2$.

My try: Define $$\phi(x)= \frac{1-x+[x]}{x^2},\quad f(x)= x^{1-\bar{\rho}}\quad\text{and}\quad g(x)= x^{{\rho}},$$
then $\phi(x)\geq 0$.

And f(x) and g(x) are continuous in $[1,\infty)$. So by [mean value theorem for improper integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712287/mean-value-theorem-for-improper-integrals?r=SearchResults) there exist some c$\in(1,\infty)$ such that
$$\frac{\mid \int_{x=1}^\infty(\frac{1-x+[x]}{x^2})x^{1-\bar{\rho}} dx\mid}{  \mid \int_{x=1}^\infty(\frac{1-x+[x]}{x^2})x^\rho dx\mid  }=\mid\frac{c^{1-\bar{\rho}}}{c^{\rho}}\mid=1$$
$$\implies c^{1-2\Re(\rho)}=1$$
$$\implies(1-2\Re(\rho))\log c=0$$
$c>1$, gives $$\Re(\rho)=1/2.$$

Comment: Why Riemann hypothesis and Riemann zeta function tag is attached?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter because $\Re(\rho)=1/2$ comes into play. Please answer.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter It is also given that $0<\Re(\rho)<1$

Comment: I don't know whether RZ is related to your given integral but the integrand is a complex function so mean value theorem is not valid.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter Then any other way to solve? Note that $\Re(\rho)=1/2$ or $\rho=1/2+it $ satisfy the given integral.

Comment: If your statement is true then you may be able to use the injectivity property of the Mellin transform, i.e. $\mathcal{M}f=\mathcal{M}g\iff f=g$. The Mellin transform is usually over $\mathbb{R}_+$ but I've seen it defined over $\mathbb{R}_{>1}$ somewhere else. (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform)

Comment: @Pixel Can you please write it as an answer. I will give you a check mark. Please. I am unable to get you but it looks good.

Comment: @Pixel is this true when f is a complex function??? Here $\rho$ is complex constant

Comment: Yes the Mellin transform is defined for complex exponents.

Comment: @Pixel so can you please explain how to get $\Re(\rho)=1/2$?

Comment: @Shreyaanand it is considered poor form to badger people to respond.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true. For $\Re(s) > 1$ and by analytic continuation for $\Re(s) >0$
$$F(s)=\int_1^\infty (1-x+\lfloor x\rfloor)x^{-s-1}dx=\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}-\frac1{s-1}+\frac1s$$

Then $|F(1/4)/F(1-1/4)| > 1$ and $|F(1/4+2i)/F(1-1/4-2i)| < 1$ thus any curve $1/4\to 1/4+2i$ passes through a point where $|F(s)/F(1-s)|=1$.

[image]

Comment: What if i get rid of the modulus?

Comment: $F(s)-F(1-s)$ has a zero near every zero of $\zeta(s)$ so if the RH is false.. If the RH is true then it is possible that its critical strip zeros are all on $\Re(s)=1/2$.